# Can I display a local variable as specific struct/data type while debugging?

Tags: c++, windbg

I'm debugging a program that I have the symbols of, and I'm trying to check what is the value inside a given variable - `data` from the WinDbg console.

The declaration of `data` is as follow: `std::vector<unsigned char> data;`, but I know that it contains a struct, let's call it `MY_STRUCT`.

Is there any easy way to display the values that stored in `data` like it has been initialized as `MY_STRUCT` data type?

In my case `MY_STRUCT` is long and complex structure that I can't understand by only looking at the output of: `dv data`.

Thank you.

Comment: a vector is 100% not any other struct.
Do you mean that the `vector` contains a series of bytes and these bytes contain are the struct you want?

Comment: For debugging, a C pointer cast may help (if applied to the raw array pointer inside the `std::vector`).

Comment: @Raildex Yeah, I mean that it was initially decaled as a `vector` but then `memcpy` has been used to change the bytes series within the given pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after searching in the documentation and trying a few methods, I have found two possible solutions:

First - using `dt` command:

```cpp
dt -a <ADDRESS_OF_DATA> MY_STRUCT
```

Second option:

```cpp
dt MY_STRUCT <ADDRESS_OF_DATA>
```